# Dynamically aproach for fetching the infinity list of data

Tags: java, opc-ua

1. Based on the root folder name I am finding the list of child folders using the find methode.
2. Again I'm passing the child node for fetching subchild nodes using the find method below is my code:

```java
List<ReferenceDescription> objectReferences = client.getAddressSpace()
                    .browse(client.getAddressSpace().getNamespaceTable().toNodeId(r.getNodeId()));
            /// 19 index
            for (int i = 0; i < objectReferences.size(); i++) {// 0.....19
                ReferenceDescription rr = objectReferences.get(i);
                List<ReferenceDescription> childereference = client.getAddressSpace()
                        .browse(client.getAddressSpace().getNamespaceTable().toNodeId(rr.getNodeId()));
                if (!childereference.isEmpty()) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < childereference.size(); j++) {// 0.......10
                        ReferenceDescription rrr = childereference.get(j);
                        List<ReferenceDescription> child1ereference = client.getAddressSpace()
                                .browse(client.getAddressSpace().getNamespaceTable().toNodeId(rrr.getNodeId()));
                        if (!child1ereference.isEmpty()) {
                            for (int k = 0; k < child1ereference.size(); k++) {// 0.......10
                                ReferenceDescription rrrr = child1ereference.get(k);
                                List<ReferenceDescription> child2ereference = client.getAddressSpace().browse(
                                        client.getAddressSpace().getNamespaceTable().toNodeId(rrrr.getNodeId()));
                                if (!child2ereference.isEmpty()) {
                                    for (ReferenceDescription description : child2ereference) {

                                        mapObjects.put(description.getBrowseName(),
                                                settheNodeId(description.getNodeId()));

                                    }
                                } else {
                                    mapObjects.put(rrrr.getBrowseName(), settheNodeId(rrrr.getNodeId()));
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            mapObjects.put(rrr.getBrowseName(), settheNodeId(rrr.getNodeId()));

                        }

                    }
                } else {
                    mapObjects.put(rr.getBrowseName(), settheNodeId(rr.getNodeId()));

                }
            }
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            System.out.println("No such item: ");
        }
```

I want the dynamic approach for structured view:

[image: img1]

I want the dynamic approach for this data structure.